# Rasclock with Raspbian Buster not working

Tags: pi-3b+, raspbian-buster, rtc

the rasclock is detected by the raspberry Pi but if I want to read or set the time on it I got the error

```
hwclock: ioctl(RTC_RD_TIME) to /dev/rtc0 to read the time failed: Remote I/O error
```

dmesg output is:

```
[  165.915983] rtc-pcf2127-i2c 1-0051: pcf2127_rtc_set_time: err=-121
[  165.916127] rtc-pcf2127-i2c 1-0051: pcf2127_rtc_read_time: read error
```

Raspbian Version is:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
```

and i2c puts out this:

```
         0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- 09 -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- 35 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- UU -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

My config.txt contains following: (Everything above is commented)

```
# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtparam=i2s=on
dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable infrared communication.
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=17
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=18

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
#dtparam=audio=on

[pi4]
# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver on top of the dispmanx display stack
#dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
#max_framebuffers=2

[all]
#dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d

dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,pcf2127
dtoverlay=mcp2515-can0,oscillator=16000000,interrupt=25
dtoverlay=spi-bcm2835-overlay
dtoverlay=i2c-bcm2835-overlay
dtoverlay=spi1-3cs

#start-up blinking
dtparam=act_led_gpio=7,act_led_trigger=timer
```

The File /lib/udev/hwclock-set is configured like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Reset the System Clock to UTC if the hardware clock from which it
# was copied by the kernel was in localtime.

dev=$1

#if [ -e /run/systemd/system ] ; then
#    exit 0
#fi

if [ -e /run/udev/hwclock-set ]; then
    exit 0
fi

if [ -f /etc/default/rcS ] ; then
    . /etc/default/rcS
fi

# These defaults are user-overridable in /etc/default/hwclock
BADYEAR=no
HWCLOCKACCESS=yes
HWCLOCKPARS=
HCTOSYS_DEVICE=rtc0
if [ -f /etc/default/hwclock ] ; then
    . /etc/default/hwclock
fi

if [ yes = "$BADYEAR" ] ; then
    #/sbin/hwclock --rtc=$dev --systz --badyear
    /sbin/hwclock --rtc=$dev --hctosys --badyear
else
    #/sbin/hwclock --rtc=$dev --systz
    /sbin/hwclock --rtc=$dev --hctosys
fi

# Note 'touch' may not be available in initramfs
> /run/udev/hwclock-set
```

The Clock is at least registered:

```
lcg@lcg-0123917fbb6e29ba01:~ $ dmesg  | grep rtc
[    5.854858] rtc-pcf2127-i2c 1-0051: pcf2127_rtc_read_time: read error
[    5.855118] rtc-pcf2127-i2c 1-0051: rtc core: registered rtc-pcf2127-i2c as rtc0
```

Comment: Do you mean this device? https://afterthoughtsoftware.com/products/rasclock It may help if you show the config.txt and the file /lib/udev/hwclock-set Did you run the commands as sudo?  I also note that page does not mention Buster - what install instructions did you follow?

Comment: Yes I mean this device! Buster is the latest Version and I think it's also the only available Version on https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/ ? 
I've added the config.txt and the /lib/udev/hwclock-set file

Answer (score 1):

I have a PCF2127 working on Buster.

I placed the following line in `/boot/config.txt`:

```
dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,pcf212
```

right after the *Enable Audio* lines and above the *[pi4]*.

I did not make any changes to the `/lib/udev/hwclock-set` file.

**Pre** Buster you had to make the changes that you have in your `/lib/udev/hwclock-set` file above plus comment out the 2 lines that have `--systz` in them.  It appears that with Buster some changes were made that allows the PCF2127 to work **without** making changes to the `hwclock-set` file.

As stated in the [Setup Guide](https://afterthoughtsoftware.com/products/rasclock), the first time you use the clock you will need to set the time. To copy the system time into the clock module:

```
sudo hwclock -w
```

After that you should be able to read (and copy) the time from the RTC using the parameters `-r` and `-s`.